# Retrieving the null value from Sqlite database in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

Guys i have stored a null value in the column of sqlite database

the value that is storing is  `return "null"`

Now using following code to retrieve it

```
int i = resultSet.getInt(resultSet.getColumnIndex(columnName));
String str = resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex(columnName));
boolean bool = resultSet.isNull(resultSet.getColumnIndex(columnName));

if( str == null ) {
    return -1;
}            
return i;
```

The debugger shows the value of `str = "null"`

but this condition is not working with `str == null , str == "" , str == "null"`

anyone can give me a hit of what to do..

Also `resultset.isNull` gives me a value of false.

So how can i store null in database, secondly if i use "null" then how can i make this condition work.

Comment: Plz add the code where you are adding null value to database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have stored the "null" literal string in the database, you compare against it like so --

```
if ( "null".equals(str) )
```

To store a null value in your database table, you use [PreparedStatement.setNull()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: can u give an idea of how can i use these preparedStatement? any small example

Comment: PreparedStatment might be overkill. You can probably just use `sqlitedb.execSQL("insert into yourtable values(null, ...");`

Comment: mDb.execSQL(updateQuery, valVars); USING this and null as one of the arguments stored in valVar but it gives error of null pointer exception

Answer (score 0):

> Also resultset.isNull gives me a value of false.

resultset.isNull will give true if your your value = null. But as you said your value = "null" , which is a String.

> The debugger shows the value of str = "null"
>
> but this condition is not working with str == null , str == "" , str == "null"

try comparing with str.equals("null")

> mDb.execSQL(updateQuery, valVars); USING this and null as one of the arguments stored in valVar but it gives error of null pointer exception

As sepcified on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html this method should be used to - Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.

Please try using update(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs) or updateWithOnConflict(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs, int conflictAlgorithm). Also please cross verify that your field in db allows NULL(i.e. Not Null = 0)

hope this helps :)

Comment: actually i need to run sql statements and using Update and others i can't use sql statements...

Answer (score -1):

Check for String length.like,

if(str.length == 0){
}

Comment: yes you right .But if nothing in string means length is zero right?

Comment: No one discussed "nothing in string".